# Close pop-up window when scrolling

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

- My situation is the following:

I have a WordPress eCommerce website with several products on it. On the product pages, obiously there are pictures of the product. When you select the picture, it opens a pop-up screen with an enlarged version of the product picture.

Recently I have noticed that, when people open the product image pop-up on a mobile device, they start scrolling. I assume this is because they expect the pop-up to close when scrolling.

All these functions (product page, product image pop-up) are created by WordPress plugin WooCommerce. The layout and style are created by my selected WordPress Theme. This means I have access to some funtions but changing things like JavaScript is not an easy thing to do.

- So my question is:

Is there a way to add functionality to close the product image pop-up when scrolling on a mobile device?

Thanks in advance for any help, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be close easily.

1. You can do from your page builder option Like Elementor, WPBakery Page Builder or anything that are you use.
2. Secondly you can close it using JavaScript.
3. You can do from your Theme Option.

Thank you Hope it will Help you

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Atiqur. I am still a bit in the dark though.. 1: Elementor does not allow me to edit these elements. 2: What would the JS script look like and where should I implement it? 3: My theme options unfortunately do not have the options to edit the product image functionality :-(